# Download apk file to Android device, and run it - doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, apk

I'm writing short program to download apk file and run it, intending to build company-wide distribution point. Program downloads file correctly, but if I try to start it (install it) on Android device, it shows "Can't open file". If I manually copy same file from PC to device and run it, it installs correctly. Application is XAMARIN.FORMS C#. Installation from unknown sources on device is Enabled.
Here's code to download it:

```
    private async void dnl(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
                
                string url = "http://192.168.0.1:8080/com.companyname.test_publishinggp.apk";
                
                var downloadManager = CrossDownloadManager.Current;
                var file = downloadManager.CreateDownloadFile(url);
                downloadManager.Start(file,true);
                UserDialogs.Instance.Progress("Downloading").Show();
                bool isDownloading = true;
                while (isDownloading)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    if (file.TotalBytesExpected > 0)
                    {
                        UserDialogs.Instance.Progress().PercentComplete = (int)(file.TotalBytesWritten / file.TotalBytesExpected * 100);
                        Console.WriteLine(("DOWNLOAD PROGRESS: " + file.TotalBytesWritten / file.TotalBytesExpected * 100).ToString() + "%");
                    }
                    isDownloading = IsDownloading(file);
                }
                //Open download location:
                Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ActionViewDownloads);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
            bool IsDownloading(IDownloadFile file)
            {
                if (file == null) return false;
    
                switch (file.Status)
                {
                    case DownloadFileStatus.INITIALIZED:
                    case DownloadFileStatus.PAUSED:
                    case DownloadFileStatus.PENDING:
                    case DownloadFileStatus.RUNNING:
                        return true;
    
                    case DownloadFileStatus.COMPLETED:
                    case DownloadFileStatus.CANCELED:
                    case DownloadFileStatus.FAILED:
                        return false;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
```

And here is addition to MainActivity.cs:

```
CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file =>
            {
                string fileName = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Url).Path.Split('/').Last();
                return Path.Combine(ApplicationContext.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName);

            });
```

Comment: What do you mean with running an apk file? And what die you mean with -and happens when- Open download location? I see no code where you try to install an apk file.

Comment: You can see I'm showing Download Manager, where file is shown. Than if I tap file, it says "Can't open file". You're right, there's no code for installation, yet. This application is intended to distribute new versions of programs, already installed on device. "Running apk file" means installing it.

Comment: Could you make sure that you have downloaded the file correctly? Please check the link below about the download file via `DownloadManager`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576352/how-to-download-files-like-the-native-browser-with-xamarin-webview-on-android/68663904#68663904

Comment: I changed code so it donwloads some jpg file from same location instead of apk file - it works fine (jpg opens when i tap it in download manager). Then, I switched back to apk file and download it again - it says "can't open file". I moved downloaded file to other location in Android device and tap it - now it installs. It seems there's something with download directory... Thanks Wendy...

Comment: @Vlada how did you moved the downloaded file to another location?