# Im unable to download the some of the files in android 11 using xamarin forms

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im unable to download the some of the files in android 11 using xamarin forms. The below manifest code im using.please assist im  a begginer to xamarin forms.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ahrM.jpg)
[im unable to find out error in android 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8WNh.png)

Comment: Where are your Read/Write external storage permissions? Also what is the exact error you are getting? Writing "unable to download some of the files" doesn't really describe the issue, we can only guess what you mean.

Comment: Even added Read and write external storage permission im facing the same iissue(Error occured) while downloading the file in android 11. It is working fine in android 10 and android 10 below versions.
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/> 
 <application android:label="Sample Parent App" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Okay Bro Sorry i dont know .im new to this environment

Comment: Posting a screenshot of "Error Occured" doesn't help us. If you are showing this toast, then there is probably an exception with a stack trace that tells us more. But with the very _limited_ information you've provided we cannot help you.

Comment: @gaddaraju I am not sure what caused this issue without details of error message. If you have set the correct permissions, you could refer to the thread i done before about how to download the file with DownloadManager. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576352/how-to-download-files-like-the-native-browser-with-xamarin-webview-on-android/68663904#68663904

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When i tapped the attached  files to download the below im using
        private  void Download_TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PortalAttachments attachment = ((TappedEventArgs)e).Parameter as PortalAttachments;
                byte[] attachmentbyte = attachment.Attachment;
                DependencyService.Get<IDownloadManager>().SaveFileToDisk(attachment.FileName, attachmentbyte);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
            }

        }

Comment: @gaddaraju Do you get any exception? The code in the link work for me to dowload the image from url.

Comment: Thanks for reply .Yes ,Access to the path /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ is denied in android 11. It is working fine in android or below version. To save the file in storage the below code im using
var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
Thanks in advance

Comment: `var dir= Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;`
The above path(/storage/emulated/0/dwonload/) worked for me in android 11 and below to save the files.

Comment: I have Summed in the reply. Hope this would be helpful to anyone who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation below, you need to use the permissions `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest if you are targeting Android 11/API 30.

Android 11 will not recognize `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets Android 11:

1. Set the preserveLegacyExternalStorage flag to true to preserve the
   legacy storage model so that your app can migrate a user's data when
   they upgrade to the new version of your app that targets Android 11.
2. Continue to opt out of scoped storage so that your app can continue
   to access your files in the legacy storage location on Android 10
   devices.

For more details, please check the link below. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#if_your_app_targets

Use `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads` instead of `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim`.

Use the `DownloadManager` download the files.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
    request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
    request.SetDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Forms.Context, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "hello.jpg");
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.App.Application.DownloadService);
    dm.Enqueue(request);
```

For more code, you could check the sample i done before.
[How to download files like the native browser with Xamarin WebView on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576352/how-to-download-files-like-the-native-browser-with-xamarin-webview-on-android/68663904#68663904)