# Can't access to a distant .apk file

Tags: android, xamarin, android-fileprovider

I'm adding to my app an update feature, the app has to check if an .apk file is newer on a distant server.
But my problem is that the file provider can't access to it.

The .apk file is available at the location, I can download it with my browser.

Here is the code I use, found on stackoverflow's posts:

the file access code :

```
        Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File(@"http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/WsAgro/MAJ/XXXXXXX.apk");

        var downloadUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "com.example.unity.fileprovider", f);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage);
        i.SetDataAndType(downloadUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
        i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
        StartActivity(i);
```

The manifest (I tried a lot of permissions while searching the issue):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0.2" package="Akanea.TPAndroid" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application>
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.example.unity.fileprovider" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:exported="false">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

The provider path :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
  </paths>
</configuration>
```

Here the exception :

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the constructor for `Java.IO.File` accepts a string path or a URI object.  You are passing the URI as a string, which it interprets as a path.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.io.file.-ctor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: changed to that :             Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File(new Java.Net.URI("http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/WsAgro/MAJ/XXXXXXXapk"));   but I got an exception, it seems that the URI needs to be build with a scheme

Comment: It seems you use the correct way. Have you recheck the URI string?

Comment: The URI string is ok, I can download the .apk file with a browser.

Comment: So have you solve this issue? And what is the exception?

Comment: No, I have the same issue, the exception is still the one in my question. I'm looking at  xamarin cross Download manager to try something else.

Comment: I am not sure how you download the file. You could check the link below about DownloadManager. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576352/how-to-download-files-like-the-native-browser-with-xamarin-webview-on-android/68663904#68663904